# SQLite insert does not work in DAL, no errors appear?

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlite, data-access-layer

I'm new with SQlite database. 
I'm trying to insert a new record in sqlite db table "time_sheet_info",
i invoke the DAL method from an .asmx WebService; & get no errors; the ExecuteNonQuery returns 1; but no data appears. 
I've tried to execute the insert command inside the WebService; it worked perfectly there!!

Any suggestions? 
 
**NOTE: i access the WS using an auto-generated PROXY.

#### GUI:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SaveDataDolCls data = new SaveDataDolCls();
            data.intProjectID = 1;
            data.intTaskID = 1;

            WebService1 wsp = new WebService1();
            wsp.saveData(data);
        }
    }
```

#### WS:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void saveData(SaveDataDolCls arrData)
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            obj1.SaveData(arrData);
        }

    }
```

#### DAL:

```
SaveDataDolCls obj = new SaveDataDolCls();
    public void SaveData(SaveDataDolCls arrData)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection())
        {
            string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DB\\MySqliteDb.db");
            string connStr = "data source= " + dbPath + "; version=3;";
            conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
            conn.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into time_sheet_info (project_id, task_id) values ('1','3');";
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't insert the data to your database by "no data appears"? ExecuteNonQuery returning 1 actually means that it inserted 1 row afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `scope.Complete` at the end of `using` block i.e.:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    obj1.SaveData(arrData);
    scope.Complete();
}
```